# Descifrar caligrafía antigua Certificado Nacimiento

Tags: historia, españa, palabras-raras, letras, parentesco

Estoy realizando un trabajo de investigación del árbol genealógico de mi familia, me estoy encontrando caligrafía antigua difícil de descifrar. 
Quería ver si me podían ayudar a descifrar que nombre/apellido y municipio de Cuenca pone. Gracias de antemano.

[image]

Comment: En la Wikipedia hay un [listado de municipios de Cuenca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Municipios_de_la_provincia_de_Cuenca) pero no veo ninguno con patrón parecido

Comment: Por cierto, nótese que existe un sitio llamado [genealogy.se] en esta misma red dedicado a la genealogía. En inglés, eso sí.

Comment: Disculpa si hice mal, echare un vistazo a lo que me comentas.

Comment: No pasa nada. La que planteaste es un tipo de preguntas que aceptamos en el sitio. Comenté lo del otro sitio por si te resulta de utilidad

Answer (score 3):

No había leído bien tu pregunta y creía que la primera línea correspondía también a una localidad. Al igual que fedorqui, no la localizaba entre los municipios de Cuenca.

Mi suposicion es que "y de" parece decir "Alfonsa Huertas", mientras que "natural de" parece poner "la misma". Misma localidad que el cónyuge de Alfonsa, supongo.
El término municipal no se ha rellenado, tiene una barra, porque coincide con la localidad.

En resumen, los datos de localidad/municipio de Alfonsa coinciden, creo, con los de su cónyuge.

Comment: Muchas gracias, agradezco enormemente la ayuda, 4 ojos ven más que dos ;)